# Argument not valid for hostnameport in netsh http delete sslcert

Tags: windows, powershell, netsh

I am trying to run the following command in PowerShell:

Command-

```
netsh http delete sslcert hostnameport="services.localtest.me:443"
```

Result-

```
'hostnameport' is not a valid argument for this command.
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.
```

I am getting an error stating that hostnameport is not a valid argument, however it is documented on [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307229(v=vs.85).aspx) as a Community Addition. Also, if you look in some of the GitHub repos from Microsoft, you'll see it being used, such as in [this PowerShell script](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/master/tools/Enable-LocalTestMe.ps1).

Is this argument only valid on specific versions of Windows? Is it only available on Windows Server? Can I enable something in Windows Features to make this argument work?

Comment: What happens when you run `netsh http delete sslcert`. It should print the help with examples. If you think it is a version issue, what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Read the doc.  `netsh http add sslcert` supports the `hostnameport` argument.  `netsh http delete sslcert` does not.  Compare `netsh http add sslcert ?` and `netsh http delete sslcert ?`.

Comment: Here is the output:

Parameters:

    Tag       Value
    ipport -  The IPv4 or IPv6 address and port for which the SSL
              certificate bindings will be deleted.

I am on Windows 7 SP1, but I have Windows Management Framework 5.0 installed.

Comment: @BaconBits what is "the doc"? I am not seeing anything to back up your comment.

Comment: @BaconBits It is supported in some environments, at least on 2012 R2 it is: "Usage: delete sslcert ipport=<ipaddr:port> | hostnameport=<name:port> | ccs=<port>"

Comment: @mikez I see it on 2012 R2 as well, but it's not on my 2008 R2 systems.  It must be a recent addition.  The doc he links is for 2008, so I assumed that's what he's on.  I doubt it's there.

Comment: @mikez do you know if this functionality is tied to the operating system, or can it be installed via an SDK or developer kit?

Comment: in general, each SSL binding require unique IP but from windows server 2012 onward there's an update of SNI support where you can assign multiple SSL binding using domain name on single IP Address and that's when the support of hostnameport argument started in. So, it won't work in older server OS.

Answer (score 5):

Please use the following command

```
netsh http delete sslcert hostnameport=localhost:443
```

Ref :http://www.it-word.net/command/Windows/netsh/en-us/netshhttp.html